# Changing output font style of a referred label

Tags: fonts, formatting, lists, labels

In of the bulleted list of my MWE below, I'd like

- the label ("Item a") to be of bold font weight,
- the output of `\ref{itm:one}` to be in normal font weight.

Unfortunately, neither the placement of `\normalfont` nor `\mdfont` in front of the command will change the font weight of the output of `\ref`; it remains in bold font weigth. Any hints to solve this?

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries{Item \alph*}]
 \item Item one\label{itm:one}
 \item Item two
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:one}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is `enumitem` solution (easiest) -- `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Item \alph*},ref={Item \alph*}]`. But why you don't want it?

Comment: I tried various solutions with the enumitem-package but all of them seemed to be incompatible with the large number of other settings I've made in my document; but this one seems to work. Awesome!

Comment: If this is what the guidlines of stackexchange.com are saying (that there's a need of a (formal) answer and a helpful comment isn't enough), then my answer is yes; your comment was the perfect solution for me!
(I'm a newbie, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Yes, this is what we follow here. At the same time accepted answers help future readers in their search. You may want to see our [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}    
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Item \alph*},,ref={Item \alph*}]
 \item Item one
 \item Item two \label{itm:one}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The changes to label made in this way are only local. You can make them global by `\setlist` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{%
  label=\textbf{Item \alph*},
  ref={Item \alph*}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Item one
 \item Item two \label{itm:one}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{itm:one}

\end{document}
```

You can define a new enumerate environment also, if needed, so that regular `enumerate` environment is still available:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{%
  label=\textbf{Item \alph*},
  ref={Item \alph*}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{myenumerate}
 \item Item one
 \item Item two \label{itm:one}
\end{myenumerate}

\ref{itm:one}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item Item one
 \item Item two 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For details refer `enumitem` documentation.